# LaunchConfiguration it's just stalling (IAM policy is having Admin priviledge) with 2 configSets in Cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Let me know how do I delete the stack after TTL. Seems 2 configsets are not working..

```
"All" : [ "ConfigureSampleApp", "ConfigureTTL" ]
```

Comment: Could you post your cloudformation template? what is resource are you trying to create?

Comment: https://aws-cfn-examples.s3.amazonaws.com/Stack_TTL.template

Comment: Seems it's no working

Comment: Comment" : "Install a simple application",
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
          "configSets" : {
            "install_all" : [ "ConfigureSampleApp", "ConfigureTTL" ]
          },

Comment: "ConfigureTTL" : {
            "files" : {
               "/usr/local/bin/deletestack.sh" : {
                "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [ "aws cloudformation delete-stack --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, " --stack-name ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" } ]]},
                "mode"    : "000400",
                "owner"   : "root",
                "group"   : "root"
              }
          },
          "commands" : {
             "schedule_stack_deletion" : {
             "command" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [ "at -f /usr/local/

Comment: "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
             "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
             "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",

             "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
             "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
             "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
             "         --configsets install_all ",
             "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",

             "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? '", { "Ref" : "WebServerWaitHandle" }, "'\n"
          ]]}}
      }

Comment: It will automatically deleted. is your stack not deleted after TTL?